# Strange Meteor Error: [Log] Exception from Deps recompute function: NotFoundError: DOM Exception 8

Tags: javascript, meteor

This is such a random error message? What are good troubleshooting tips to track where this is coming from?

SAFARI Console:

```
[Log] Exception from Deps recompute function: NotFoundError: DOM Exception 8 (meteor.js, line 741)
insertBefore@[native code]
_insertNodeWithHooks@http://10.0.0.9/packages/blaze.js?cf9aea283fb9b9d61971a3b466bff429f9d66d7d:349:24
_insert@http://10.0.0.9/packages/blaze.js?cf9aea283fb9b9d61971a3b466bff429f9d66d7d:318:36
attach@http://10.0.0.9/packages/blaze.js?cf9aea283fb9b9d61971a3b466bff429f9d66d7d:395:23
_insert@http://10.0.0.9/packages/blaze.js?cf9aea283fb9b9d61971a3b466bff429f9d66d7d:313:13
attach@http://10.0.0.9/packages/blaze.js?cf9aea283fb9b9d61971a3b466bff429f9d66d7d:395:23
_insert@http://10.0.0.9/packages/blaze.js?cf9aea283fb9b9d61971a3b466bff429f9d66d7d:313:13
attach@http://10.0.0.9/packages/blaze.js?cf9aea283fb9b9d61971a3b466bff429f9d66d7d:395:23
setMembers@http://10.0.0.9/packages/blaze.js?cf9aea283fb9b9d61971a3b466bff429f9d66d7d:438:18
doMaterialize@http://10.0.0.9/packages/blaze.js?cf9aea283fb9b9d61971a3b466bff429f9d66d7d:1877:32
nonreactive@http://10.0.0.9/packages/deps.js?02d2ad4c6472ce004db73ba12c99864ab9acb468:397:13
doRender@http://10.0.0.9/packages/blaze.js?cf9aea283fb9b9d61971a3b466bff429f9d66d7d:1868:23
http://10.0.0.9/packages/blaze.js?cf9aea283fb9b9d61971a3b466bff429f9d66d7d:1813:20
withCurrentView@http://10.0.0.9/packages/blaze.js?cf9aea283fb9b9d61971a3b466bff429f9d66d7d:2046:16
viewAutorun@http://10.0.0.9/packages/blaze.js?cf9aea283fb9b9d61971a3b466bff429f9d66d7d:1812:33
_compute@http://10.0.0.9/packages/deps.js?02d2ad4c6472ce004db73ba12c99864ab9acb468:229:36
_recompute@http://10.0.0.9/packages/deps.js?02d2ad4c6472ce004db73ba12c99864ab9acb468:243:22
flush@http://10.0.0.9/packages/deps.js?02d2ad4c6472ce004db73ba12c99864ab9acb468:337:24
```

Chrome Debug:

```
Exception from Deps recompute function: Error: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node.
    at Error (native)
    at Function.DOMRange._insertNodeWithHooks (http://10.0.0.9/packages/blaze.js?cf9aea283fb9b9d61971a3b466bff429f9d66d7d:349:12)
    at Function.DOMRange._insert (http://10.0.0.9/packages/blaze.js?cf9aea283fb9b9d61971a3b466bff429f9d66d7d:318:16)
    at DOMRange.attach (http://10.0.0.9/packages/blaze.js?cf9aea283fb9b9d61971a3b466bff429f9d66d7d:395:16)
    at Function.DOMRange._insert (http://10.0.0.9/packages/blaze.js?cf9aea283fb9b9d61971a3b466bff429f9d66d7d:313:7)
    at DOMRange.attach (http://10.0.0.9/packages/blaze.js?cf9aea283fb9b9d61971a3b466bff429f9d66d7d:395:16)
    at Function.DOMRange._insert (http://10.0.0.9/packages/blaze.js?cf9aea283fb9b9d61971a3b466bff429f9d66d7d:313:7)
    at DOMRange.attach (http://10.0.0.9/packages/blaze.js?cf9aea283fb9b9d61971a3b466bff429f9d66d7d:395:16)
    at DOMRange.setMembers (http://10.0.0.9/packages/blaze.js?cf9aea283fb9b9d61971a3b466bff429f9d66d7d:438:12)
    at doMaterialize (http://10.0.0.9/packages/blaze.js?cf9aea283fb9b9d61971a3b466bff429f9d66d7d:1877:22)
```

Comment: On which console is this error printed? Server or browser? If the latter, which browser is it?

Comment: debugging in safari. this is from the client console window...

Comment: Can you try using Chrome? I don't know why, but I get way more explicit errors when I use my app on Chrome.

Comment: Added chrome debug...

Comment: You could try using the _zones_ package, as suggested in [this MeteorHacks post about client-side debugging](https://meteorhacks.com/client-side-debugging-for-meteor-apps.html).

Comment: Maybe [this link](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2373) is helping?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the Chrome error, you have a jQuery `insertBefore` statement that’s referencing something invalid. Search your code for `insertBefore` and comment them out one at a time until you make the error message disappear. If you don’t have any `insertBefore`s in your code, it’s being called by a plugin or something lower-level.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know what is it, but after restarting meteor app, exception is gone.